# How to show $1 + \sqrt{ 5 }$ is irreducible

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to show that $p = 1 + \sqrt{ 5 }$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{ Z }\left(\sqrt{ 5 }\right)$. After applying the norm $N\left(a + b\sqrt{ 5 }\right) = a^2 - 5b^2$, I find that $N(p) = -4 = -2 \cdot 2$. So naturally I'm trying to solve the equation $a^2 - 5b^2 = \pm 2$.

How exactly would one go about finding solutions to such an equation, or rather their nonexistence? I would very much appreciate a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: go modulo something? :O Not sure if that helps...

Comment: Modulo five? ${}$

Comment: Modulo $5$ would definitely work :) for $a\in \mathbb{Z}_5$ see that $a^2\in \{0,1,4\}$.. Does this help somehow???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All squares of integers are congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4. Further, multiplying by 5 does not change the equivalence of $b^2$ modulo 4, since $5b^2=b^2+4b^2\equiv b^2\mod 4$. The difference of $0/1$ mod 4 by another $0/1$ mod 4 can only yield $0,1,3$ mod 4. Therefore there are no integral solutions.

As the comments above suggest, modulo 5 also works, since the only squares modulo 5 are 0,1,4, and we precisely need a square equivalent to 2 or 3.